# apt dpkg error Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: apt, 17.10

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 kde-runtime : Depends: oxygen-icon-theme but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I then get this;

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  oxygen-icon-theme
The following NEW packages will be installed
  oxygen-icon-theme
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
128 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/30.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 37.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 288663 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../oxygen-icon-theme_5%3a5.38.0-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking oxygen-icon-theme (5:5.38.0-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/oxygen-icon-theme_5%3a5.38.0-0ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/share/icons/oxygen/base/32x32/actions/align-horizontal-bottom-out.png.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/oxygen-icon-theme_5%3a5.38.0-0ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm not trying to install kde so I don't know where this comes from and want rid od it as it's broken `apt install` command

Comment: That's the frustrated-but-still-wrong reason to uninstall a package. *Something* you have installed depends upon that package.  Delete the package from `/var/cache/apt/archives`, and then try `sudo apt --fix-broken install` again.

Comment: That is an odd error. Can you try `sudo apt autoremove -f` If that fails tell us more. Is this an upgrade? What package did you install to get here and how? Ppa? Downloaded .deb ? Have you changed ownership of permissions of system files ?